# Execute Python (CGI) File from HTML Form in Bootstrap. JS with Apache Server

Tags: javascript, python, apache, twitter-bootstrap, cgi

I have a bootstrap.js form that I'm trying to post a parameter to a python file and have that python file execute. I tried several things, made the file a .cgi file, added right permissions for cgi in config file, checked paths, etc. I can't solve it. When I push submit on the form, nothing happens; it's as if the path is never set-off. I'm wondering if there's something I'm overlooking? Some weird permission with cgi, or something to do with html forms in bootstrap.js? Or something else. The code looks like below. I searched several things online. The file executes itself correclty when I load it directly in browser directly. It just cannot be called from the form for some reason.

```
    d.append("<form action=\"/hellotrial2.py\" method=\"POST\">");
   d.append("<p>First Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"first_name\">  <br /> </p>");
   d.append("<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></p>");
   d.append("</form>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create strings with both ' and " characters in javascript. No need to escape all those quotes.

Open up the developer tools for the browser you are using, look at the POST message you're sending and the response, if any, that it gets.

Comment: When I go to developer tools and check, there's nothing. so it's not calling it. I'm not sure why. does that help??